# How do I make a locator based on custom attribute based on webpage of a hybrid app

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

I tried to use xpath for custom attribute provided by developers but getting no element found exception.

```
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/session/5fcb27d1-ab07-4d9b-b06f-cb4d006391e3/element
[HTTP] {"using":"xpath","value":"//input[@data-autoid='AC_NAME_ctrl']"}
[debug] [W3C (5fcb27d1)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["xpath","//input[@data-autoid='AC_NAME_ctrl']","5fcb27d1-ab07-4d9b-b06f-cb4d006391e3"]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, css selector, -android uiautomator
[debug] [BaseDriver] Waiting up to 10000 ms for condition
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8201/wd/hub/session/bb01926e-16fe-426e-881c-d1b4c689bc8e/element] with body: {"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//input[@data-autoid='AC_NAME_ctrl']","context":"","multiple":false}
[WD Proxy] Got response with status 404: {"sessionId":"bb01926e-16fe-426e-881c-d1b4c689bc8e","value":{"error":"no such element","message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters","stacktrace":"io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.ElementNotFoundException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.findElement(FindElement.java:90)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.safeHandle(FindElement.java:67)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:59)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:266)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:260)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:68)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerCont...
```

Code used:

```
WebElement f1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-autoid='AC_NAME_ctrl']"));
f1.sendKeys("Rahul");
```

data-autoid is custom attribute with value 'AC_NAME_ctrl'
Any help in this direction will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For hybrid apps, *Appium* has to know whether you want to automate the native aspects of the app or the web views.

Switch to web-context before interaction with web views elements.

**NOTE:** Starting from appium java client version is 8.0.0 for work with contexts, casting to `SupportsContextSwitching` might be required.

```
import io.appium.java_client.remote.SupportsContextSwitching;

contexts and find your one
((SupportsContextSwitching) driver).context("WEBVIEW_1");
// the name could be WEBVIEW_... you have to print all the available
// To avoid `ClassCastException`, the driver initially should be created as `AndroidDriver` or `IOSDriver`, 
// e.g. AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(...);
```

and then

```
WebElement f1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@data-autoid='AC_NAME_ctrl']"));
f1.sendKeys("Rahul");
```

do not forget to switch back to native.

```
((SupportsContextSwitching) driver).context("NATIVE_APP");
```

This will print all the available contexts:

```java
Set<String> contextNames = ((SupportsContextSwitching) driver).getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextName);
}
```

---

**Reference**

https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/

Comment: Hi Max i am using selenium 4.1 and appium driver java client version is 8.0.0-beta 2. These suggested  methods are not coming. Any further suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: @RahulSingh, you have to cast the driver to the Interface (SupportsContextSwitch or similar, not remember the exact name), which was introduced in appium 8. I'll add this code in few hours. Also casting appium driver to AndroidDriver will solve this, since `AndroidDriver` already implements the required interface.

Comment: @RahulSingh I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i get it right , you wanna create a locator based on the customer input ?